# How to avoid creating image thumbnail every model.save() call?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a news blog, so I decided to add a profile image. I was thinking, how to create image thumbnail better and decide to use percent resizing.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    image = Image.open(self.image)  # Открываем картинку
    width, height = image.size  # Получаем размеры картинки
    new_image = BytesIO()  # Создаем байтовое представление

    resize = (width * (height // 10 * 5) // height, height // 10 * 5)  # Изменение по высоте

    if width > height:  # Если горизонтальная картинка
        resize = (width // 10 * 5, height * (width // 10 * 5) // width)  # Изменение по ширине

    image.thumbnail(resize, resample=Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Делаем миниатюру картинки
    image = image.convert('RGB')  # Убираем все лишние каналы
    image.save(new_image, format='JPEG', quality=90)  # Конвертируем в JPEG, ибо мало весит

    new_image.seek(0)  # Возвращение в начало файла

    name = f'{self.image.name.split(".")[0]}.jpeg'  # Имя файла

    # Перезапись файла в базе данных
    self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(
        new_image, 'ImageField',  # Картинка, поля сохранения
        name, 'image/jpeg',  # Имя картинки, содержание
        getsizeof(new_image), None  # Размер, доп инфа
    )
    # Сохранение через другой save класса
    super(KvantUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So, as you can see, I take only a half of the image size. It helps to keep good quality of the picture and reduce its size. But this method cause another problem.

Every time, when `save()` method called, image become smaller and smaller...
I've tried to rewrite my change form, but it didn't help.
As I knew, Django call `save()` method every time I change model, or login in system. So, I need help to solve this problem. Maybe it's better to create a fixed thumbnail, or you know a better way to do it. Feel free to suggest any ideas!

My model.py

```
def set_default_image():
    bucket = S3Boto3Storage()
    if not bucket.exists('default/user/user.png'):
        with open(join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/default/user.png'), 'b+r') as f:
            bucket.save('default/user/user.png', f)
    return 'default/user/user.png'


def get_path(instance, filename):
    return f'user/{instance.username}/{filename}'


class KvantUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    permission = models.CharField(choices=permission, max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=color, default='blue')
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=theme, default='light')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_path, default=set_default_image)
```

My forms.py

```
class KvantUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = KvantUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'surname', 'patronymic', 'image')


class KvantUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = KvantUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'surname', 'patronymic', 'image')


class KvantUserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=150)

    def save(self, request):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']  # Получение логина
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']  # Получение пароля

        if KvantUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists():  # Проверка существования акаунта
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  # Попытка авторизации
            if user is not None:  # Если попытка удачна, то авторизуй и верни пользователя
                login(request, user)
                return user
        messages.error(request, 'Ошибка авторизации!')  # Сообщение об ощибки
        return None
```

P.S If you need another file, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to create the thumbnail when the `KvantUser` instance is created you can check if the `pk` exists before using your logic for resizing the image:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        # Your code to make the thumbnail here
    super(KvantUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But there is a better way, that is to put this logic in the **form** itself, since you have multiple forms for this model, write a mixin and inherit that in these forms:

```
class ImageThumbnailFormMixin:
    def clean_image(self):
        f = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
        if not f:
            return f
        image = f.image # A PIL Image object that Django has annotated here
        # Make the thumbnail here with the `image` object
        image.save()
        return f


class KvantUserCreationForm(ImageThumbnailFormMixin, UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = KvantUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'surname', 'patronymic', 'image')


class KvantUserChangeForm(ImageThumbnailFormMixin, UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = KvantUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'surname', 'patronymic', 'image')
```

Comment: Hmm... can you explain, what FormMixin is? Is it for expanding Forms?

Comment: @Algolmerg no not for expanding forms, Mixins are a design pattern in python used for re-usability purpose (You will notice the class `ImageThumbnailFormMixin` by itself doesn't make much sense, but when some other class inherits it that's when it makes sense). Normally you would have written that `clean_image` method in the form itself, but you would need to write it in two places, so you just wrote it in a separate class which you will inherit in both classes.

Comment: Yep, I understand. Thnks you a lot! I just change it and all works. You made my day :)

P.S, change `if not f` on `if self.instance.image == file:`, cause you variant don't work :)